# Call to undefined method CI_Input

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is the error I get, and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method CI_Input::category()

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\application\models\Category_model.php

Line Number: 23

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\application\controllers\Category.php
Line: 30
Function: create_category

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

[this is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcW08.jpg)

```
public function create()


public function create()
{
$data['title'] = 'Create Category';
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_name', 'Category Name', 'required');
if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{
   $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);     
   $this->load->view('category/create', $data);
   $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}

else{
    $this->category_model->create_category();
    redirect('category');
}
```

[this is my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY4Nj.jpg)

```
public function create_category()
{
$cat_name = url_title($this->input->category('cat_name'), 'dash', TRUE); // this is line 23, by the way..

$data = array(
    'cat_name' => $cat_name
);

return $this->db->insert('category', $data);
}
```

the message seems to be pointing at the line 23, but I think there's nothing wrong with it.

I am new, and been trying to make a little web application.

Comment: Edit your question with that code where that code is.

Comment: `url_title($this->input->post('cat_name'), 'dash', true)`

Comment: Nothing changed 

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#accessing-form-data

Comment: Wow..  What i did was funny..  Lol..  Thank you very much wolfgang1983

Comment: Your sample code never assigns this-> input so it is not clear what object it is and if it has a category() method.

Comment: @eckes, The class `input` is loaded during the CodeIgniter bootstrap so it is always instantiated and in scope to `$this->`. However, it does not have a `category` method.

Comment: You have double function `public function create()`

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys.. it really did help me :D